# How to check weather login is required or not on given url(website) to proceed

Tags: python-3.x

how to check logging is required in a website or not.

suppose i have given url in python code as:'www.amazon.com'
expected result as:'NO login is not required to proceed'.

and url='www.Facebook.com 
expected result as :'Yes login is required to proceed'

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is there a particular thing you've tried that isn't working?

Comment: This task is impossible, as a computer has no way of knowing what you mean by login required to proceed. The only way to do this is to manually make a map of each website and whether it is true or not.

Answer (score 0):

It will likely be very difficult to consistently detect whether or not you must be logged in to visit a page. There is no standard for determining this. There's a few approaches you can try:

## HTTP status

When visiting an unauthorized page, it's possible that the web server will respond with an HTTP `401` or `403` status, telling the browser that it is unauthorized to view the content. You can check for these responses and act accordingly, though it's not guaranteed or even likely that a webpage will return this response.

## Page analysis

You could scan the source of a page for HTML input boxes that are indicative of a login page. This will not work for every page, as some websites have a login form on every page when you're not logged in.

## URL analysis

You could use a model to determine whether or not the URL you followed leads to a login page. For example, if you are redirected to `https://example.com/login` when trying to access a resource, it's a good indication that you must be logged in before doing so.